# why Is my Update method not letting me get Current and Original entity values on SaveChangesAsnyc override?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-5

I have the following update method to update all fields of a record:

```
public async Task<TUsers> Update<T>(T updatedRecord, string operatorId) where T : BaseUser
{
    var operator = await MyContext.TUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.userId == operatorId);
    if (operator == null) throw new BusinessException("Action denied");

    TUsers oldRecord = await SearchUser(updatedRecord.Id);
    if (fichaAntiga == null) throw new BusinessException("User not found");

    updatedRecord.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF");
    updatedRecord.UpdatedBy = operator.Id;

    MyContext.Entry(oldRecord).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedRecord);

    await MyContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new TUsers();
}
```

I've overrided the SaveChangesAsync method on MyContext to get the old record and the new one and log them on a MongoDB collection. But the problem is that both of the properties shows the new record. Here's my override

```
 public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(change.OriginalValues);
            Console.WriteLine(change.CurrentValues);
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
```

I put a breakpoint on the beginning of the method and inspect the values inside change.OriginalValues.InternalEntry.Entity and change.CurrentValues.InternalEntry.Entity and they both have the same values, including its navigation properties.

Comment: Maybe because `MyContext.Entry(oldRecord)` - is wrong record? `oldRecord` has type `TUsers`, but you are chaniing record. with type `T`.

Comment: I don't think so. The generic type is any class that inherints from BaseUser, which are my domain entities mapped from the dbset that were scaffolded from the table... I actually can update the database with any problem, wouldn't it be possible if the type of the classes was the problem?